# Autocomplete submit form on click mouse selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, autocomplete

I've made the following form:

```html
<form action="search-engine/search.php"> 
    <input id="words" name="q" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Buscar aquí" >
    <div class="input-group-addon search-div">
        <button type="submit" id="submitForm" class="btn-search">
            <span class="fa fa-search fa-fw "></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$("#words").autocomplete({
    source: "autocomplete.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        //assign value back to the form element
        if(ui.item){
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        }
        //submit the form
        $(event.target.form).submit();
    }
});
```

The code works well. Autocomplete is running, and if you click ENTER when you have made the selection the form is submitted.

I want also to add the possibility to send the form when you click with the mouse on the selection, like Google.

I've solve changing:

```
$(event.target.form).submit();
```

With

```
document.getElementById("submitForm).click();
```

Is there another way to do it with Jquery?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you're retrieving the form. Try this:

```
$(event.target).closest('form').submit();
```

Comment: It's not working. To submit the form after the selection I need to push on the button or click ENTER